# How to add indent for equation description?

Tags: xetex

I want to achieve this:

[image: Example]

Is there a *simple* way to markup something like this? The part I'm interested is the indent of equation parameters description.

Comment: You could just use a `tabular` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use the `tabular` environment. Though it makes gaps between columns too wide for this case, so use `@{ }` to insert ordinary spaces instead. An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\[
f=f_0\exp(-\lambda t),
\]
\begin{tabular}{l@{ }l@{ }l}
где&$f$&--- ценность информации;\\
   &$f_0$&--- ценность информации в начальный момент времени;\\
   &$\lambda$&--- показатель скорости старения информации;\\
   &$t$&--- индекс времени.
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

It renders to the following:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could also format a `description`-like environment with `enumitem` to produce this kind of list. The implementation is a bit more complicated, but the code in the document itself is simpler.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcounter{variable}
\newcommand{\variablesformat}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{variable}%
    \if1\thevariable%
        где \(#1\) --%
    \else%
        \phantom{где }\(#1\) --%
    \fi%
}
\newlist{variables}{description}{1}
\setlist[variables]{%
    nosep,
    format=\normalfont\variablesformat,
    before=\setcounter{variable}{0},
}
\begin{document}
\[
f = f_0 \exp(-\lambda t)
\]
\begin{variables}
    \item[f] ценность информации
    \item[f_0] ценность информации в начальный момент времени
    \item[\lambda] показатель скорости старения информации
    \item[t] индекс времени
\end{variables}
\end{document}
```

[image]